# Model suggestion for graph for Constraing Programing solver (gecode)

Tags: constraint-programming, gecode

**Problem** : Given a labeled(1..n) undirected graph, create a model in Gecode for finding a supergraph with a given sequence degree:

**Difficulties**: the main difficulty is to find fancy model to accurately express degrees over it:

*Why not Adjacency matrix?* Because graph tends to be big and sparse

*Why not Edge list?* We are going to add edges, but we don't know how many of them, CP requires predefined number of variables (am I right?)

*Why not Adjacency list?* modeling problem as a list of sets we need to push a constraint for all i, j: (j in a[i] <=> i in a[j])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the possibilities you offer using the "Adjacency list" will probably be the best one.

Your concern is that you will have to many propagators to channel between the sets; however Gecode includes a special channeling propagator to channel between sets: http://www.gecode.org/doc-latest/reference/classGecode_1_1Set_1_1Channel_1_1ChannelSet.html. This propagator channels exactly in the way you described and should minimize the effort spend on keeping the sets consistent.